# How do I get the results of my function into a variable so that I can use it again?

Tags: vb.net

Here is an example of my function:

```
Public Class GlobalFunctions

Public Shared Function CreateNewDatabase(ByVal MyDomainName As String, ByVal NewDatabaseName As String, ByVal StatusBoxName As ListBox)

    Try

        Dim MyWorkingDirectory As String = "C:\mytest1\"
        Dim MyFileName As String = "mycmd.exe"

        If File.Exists(MyWorkingDirectory & MyFileName) Then

            'Run mycmd

            'Here are my results
            Dim Result1 As String = "r2"
            Dim Result2 As String = "r2"
            Dim Result3 As String = "r3"

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

    Return True

End Function

End Class
```

Basically what I need to do is run my function & then be able to use the results in my next function.. Something like:

```
    GlobalFunctions.CreateNewDatabase(DomainName.Text, MyDbName, StatusListBox)
    MsgBox(Result1)
    MsgBox(Result2)
    MsgBox(Result3)
```

Any help would be much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should make properties Result1, Result2, Result3 in your class and set them in CreateNewDatabase(). Then you can get them as `GlobalFunctions.Result1`

But it looks terrible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main options here.  The first is to return the values you want to use later.  To do this, you can either create a class with properties for the three values you want to use, or if this function will have limited use, you could consider returning a `Tuple` (based on your example, a `Tuple(Of String, String, String)`)

The other option is to make class level properties and set their backing fields from the `CreateNewDatabase` function.  The primary drawback to this is that these values will be overwritten by any future calls to the function.  It also introduces some discoverability issues into your API by requiring the programmer to know that three properties are set by the method, rather than the more obvious returning an object with three properties from the function.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the obviously easiest way is, declaring them as global variables, which in practice seems not to be too welcomed.

```
Public Class Form1

 Dim Result1 As String 
 Dim Result2 As String 
 Dim Result3 As String

GlobalFunctions.CreateNewDatabase(DomainName.Text, MyDbName, StatusListBox)
MsgBox(Result1)
MsgBox(Result2)
MsgBox(Result3)


etc..
etc...

end class
```

Not the prettiest way to do it, but it will get the job done.

Comment: There are some good reasons why this is not "too welcomed". Using global variables in the way you suggest is not remotely thread safe. Also, you aren't actually using global variables at all in your example - you are using private member variables.